# jquery get data attributes from dynamically generated options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a drop down dynamically after an ajax all and populating the fields. I am also calling jquery.data() to set some attribute which I want in future.

HTML

```
<input id="test" type="text" list="mylist"/>
<datalist id="mylist"></datalist>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
// assume this data is coming from ajax call
var data = [{
    "name": "John",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "name": "Jane",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "name": "Judie",
    "id": 3
}];

var generateDropDown = function(data) {
    var datalist = $('#mylist');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i].name + ' => ' + data[i].id;
        $('<option>', {
                'class': 'myclass'
            })
            .val(value)
            .data('extra', {
                'newid': data[i] * 100
            })
            .appendTo(datalist);
    }
};

generateDropDown(data);

 $('.myclass').on('select', function(selected) {
    console.log($(selected).data('extra'));
    console.log($(this).data('extra'));
 });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yb6km6a/)

My requirement is to access the selected value from drop down along with the data attribute i have added. How can I do that ?

I tried the 2 console.log options as mentioned above but they dont print anything.

Comment: Why are you using a datalist instead of a select? A Dadaist is a suggestion, the user can type whatever he/she wants an then you won't get any data elements.

Comment: I want to create an autocomplete list, thats why I am using datalist. Please suggest if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: @Raghuveer There are many autocomplete plugins, if using a plugin is an option: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: @vohuman - yeah I am aware of those plugins but my requirement is not to use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comparison to `HTMLSelectElement` object, `HTMLDataListElement` object doesn't have `selectedIndex` property, so it seems you have to `filter` the `options` for getting the *possible* selected `option`.

```
$('#test').on('change', function (/* event */) {
    var val = this.value;
    var data = $(this.list.options).filter(function() {
         return this.value === val;
    }).data('extra');
});
```

[Here is a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/5x9nep8o/)
Also note that `data[i] * 100` results in a `NaN` (Not a Number) value as you are multiplying an object by a number and it doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. And good catch on the NaN thingy.

Answer (score 2):

When using a datalist, think of it as just a list of suggestions for the user. The user can type whatever he/she wants. The option elements are not related to the actual selected value which is stored in the textbox. If you must use a datalist, then use an event on the textbox and select the option based on the value. Something like:

```
   $('#test').on('change', function(selected) {
        alert($("#mylist option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").data('extra'));
    });
```

This takes the textbox value and finds the associated datalist option. However, if I type some random gibberish, it won't and can't work since no corresponding option exists. The alternative is to use a select which forces the user to choose one of the options in the list.

If you want a select, take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/tscxyw5m/

Essentially now we can do:

```
$("#mylist").on('change', function() {
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").data("extra"));
    });
```

Because now the options are actually associated with the select.

Also note I think you meant:
`'newid': data[i].id * 100`
Not
`'newid': data[i] * 100`
Which yields NaN.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/9yb6km6a/21/

When you try to get the value of the selected item, you need to search through the options in the page and bring the option item that matches with the value in the input field:

```
$("#test").bind('input', function () {
    alert($('body')
          .find(
             'option[value*="' + $(this).val() + '"]'
          ).data('extra').newid);
});
```